# How to specify optional parameter in CREATE query using the Neo4J REST API

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm exploring the [Neo4J REST API](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api.html), and have stumbled into a problem.

I do a `POST` to `http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher` with the following body:

```
{
    "query": "CREATE (n {name: {name}, description: {description}})",
    "params": {
        "name": "Test"
    }
}
```

It returns a `400 Bad Request` with the following body:

```
{
    "message": "Expected a parameter named description",
    "exception": "ParameterNotFoundException",
    "fullname": "org.neo4j.cypher.ParameterNotFoundException",
    "stacktrace": [
       ...
   ]
}
```

How do I make the `description` parameter optional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide every parameter:

```
{
    "query": "CREATE (n {name: {name}, description: {description}})",
    "params": {
        "name": "Test",
        "description": "sometext"
    }
}
```

Check if description is provided and otherwise set it to empty string.
I think it would be better to built your query on the fly.

If discription is not provided. Built this query:

```
"CREATE (n {name: {name}})"
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid this.